# Sequence elemnt in Dict wont load properly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a `training monitor.py` for my deeplearning model where I call `callbacks` to the model. It loads a `json file` with values and loop over a keys in dict of that `json file`
Json looks like this

```
"{'val_loss': [5.237191623602158, 4.616091437362744, 4.451269820260772, 
4.362860869442862, 3.815740784710904, 3.8274743541668546, 3.9138536897172513, 
3.5977005262053416, 3.613263362866152, 3.6910251097732716], 'val_acc': 
[0.08173076923076923, 0.12489967897271267, 0.15399277688603533, 
0.17726725521669343, 0.24859550561797752, 0.25451444622792935, 
0.2510032102728732, 0.29825441412520065, 0.29674959871589085, 
0.28681781701444625], 'loss': [5.8396556760644165, 4.7136322415301155, 
4.393255534172906, 4.207402438980053, 4.045142109699782, 3.929618620266169, 
3.8373178752232295, 3.7613641902812325, 3.700959263334659, 3.647130805573047], 
'acc': [0.05180921052631579, 0.11022808109550063, 0.147663613729326, 
0.17937488884936867, 0.20855192957496, 0.2304263738218033, 
0.24964431797972614, 0.26676151520540636, 0.28015516628134446, 
0.29109238840476614]}"
```

And I was trying this code in my `training monitor.py`

```py
class TrainingMonitor(BaseLogger):
    def __init__(self, figPath, jsonPath=None, startAt=0):
        # store the output path for the figure, the path to the JSON
        # serialized file, and the starting epoch
        super(TrainingMonitor, self).__init__()
        self.figPath = figPath
        self.jsonPath = jsonPath
        self.startAt = startAt

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        # initialize the history dictionary
        self.H = {}

        # if the JSON history path exists, load the training history
        if self.jsonPath is not None:
            if os.path.exists(self.jsonPath):
                self.H = json.loads(open(self.jsonPath).read())
                print(type(self.H))

                # check to see if a starting epoch was supplied
                if self.startAt > 0:
                    # loop over the entries in the history log and
                    # trim any entries that are past the starting
                    # epoch
                    for k in self.H.keys(): # HERE it throws the ERROR
                        self.H[k] = self.H[k][:self.startAt]
```

It throws the error in this line

```
  for k in self.H.keys():
```

It should be in `dict` as I initialize the history dictionary above, but it shows

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

So I tried something like this

```
self.H = dict(json.loads(open(self.jsonPath).read()))
```

To be sure that it is in `dict` but this time it shows

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

So it will not probably work this way.... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That is **not** a JSON file. Or, more accurately, it's not a JSON file representing an *object*; it represents a string that is itself either JS or Python code but also not JSON. There are ways to deal with that, but I think you should really look into how that file is generated upstream and make it an actual JSON object.

Comment: Issue is at `open(self.jsonPath).read()`. It is not returning what you are expecting i.e., JSON file

Comment: The error clearly says the reason:


     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'



It means you are trying to call the `.keys()` method on a `str` object. Why does it happen? Try to understand why `json.loads(...)` returns a `str` instead of the Python object that you expect. (a dictionary)

Comment: thanks! I looked at json file example on the net I realized it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keys(property name) in the JSON file should be enclosed in double-quotes which are not in your JSON file.

For example, change `'val_loss'` to `"val_loss"` and there are many other keys which eclosed in single quotes change all to double quotes as well

**DEMO:**

Enclosed all property names with double-quotes,

```
{"val_loss": [5.237191623602158, 4.616091437362744, 4.451269820260772, 
4.362860869442862, 3.815740784710904, 3.8274743541668546, 3.9138536897172513, 
3.5977005262053416, 3.613263362866152, 3.6910251097732716], "val_acc": 
[0.08173076923076923, 0.12489967897271267, 0.15399277688603533, 
0.17726725521669343, 0.24859550561797752, 0.25451444622792935, 
0.2510032102728732, 0.29825441412520065, 0.29674959871589085, 
0.28681781701444625], "loss": [5.8396556760644165, 4.7136322415301155, 
4.393255534172906, 4.207402438980053, 4.045142109699782, 3.929618620266169, 
3.8373178752232295, 3.7613641902812325, 3.700959263334659, 3.647130805573047], 
"acc": [0.05180921052631579, 0.11022808109550063, 0.147663613729326, 
0.17937488884936867, 0.20855192957496, 0.2304263738218033, 
0.24964431797972614, 0.26676151520540636, 0.28015516628134446, 
0.29109238840476614]}

import json
print(type(json.loads(open('text_file_with_json_data.txt').read())))
```

---

**Output:**

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: thanks! This helped! I looked at json file example on the net I realized it